# How to overwrite an asset (PNG image) file in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

first question I've asked so please go easy, also an absolute newbie with TFS (within Visual Studio 2010 in this context).

I have spent some time seeking an answer to this question both via SA and further afield, pretty shocked at how unintuitive this process seems to be given how fundamental it is. Slightly embarrassing.

In short: Three assets are shown in Source Control (three icons). I've now created three replacement icons via GIMP that I wish to use in the project, but I can't work out how to overwrite the old ones and put my new ones up.

I have read that I should 'check out' the existing three, which I have done, but I still can't then right-click on their containing folder in TFS and choose 'Add Items to Folder' - it complains that files with these names already exist with no option to overwrite.

edit - I don't have the ability to install any add-ons or other software on my machine :(

Comment: If you install the TFS Power Tools (for example: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) then this will add TFS integration to Windows Explorer; you will then be able to check out the files to a working copy (usually a folder on your computer), overwrite them, and then check the updated binary files back in.

Comment: @dash - thanks so much for responding, but I'm not able to install any further software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have discovered, TFS defines *adding* files as creating new files in source control.  For files that exist in source control, you simply wish to *edit* them.

Once you have the files checked out, simply copy the files into place in Windows Explorer or from the command-line.  You can then check the files in.

Comment: Thank you @Edward Thompson, I trust this thread will serve anybody else resolve this basic issue in the future. :)